# how can I find selected DropDownList from List Of DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, list, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, view

I show a list in View. Every item in the list has a DropDownList that specify the status of each record. Now I want to get the selected "value in DropDownList" that is in the DropDownList.

I tried this to set DropDownList :

```
 <div>
  @Html.DropDownList("DeclineReasons", ViewBag.DeclineReasons as SelectList, new { @id=item.ProfessorSubmittedRequestFlowId+"Dec"})
</div>
```

And by click on the button, I tried to find DropDownList in record by:

```
  var SelectedDeclineReason = ProfessorSubmittedRequestFlowId + "Dec"
  var e = document.getElementById("SelectedDeclineReason");
  var SDeclineReasons = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

I tried this way too, but doesn't work neither:

```
var SelectedDeclineReason = ProfessorSubmittedRequestFlowId + "Dec"
var j=$('*[data-id=SelectedDeclineReason ]');
```

SelectedDeclineReason shows Id properly, but the element is undefined in both ways.

Comment: can you change the ID of your DDL something like this  <div>
  @Html.DropDownList("DeclineReasons", ViewBag.DeclineReasons as SelectList, new { @id="Dec"}) 
</div> .... and then in your JS you can get the Value by ("#Dec").val() ... this work for me

Comment: Sorry No,every Record Must Have Id Of Each Item.because i Want To Update Status Of Row.

Comment: So you can use Class  <div>
  @Html.DropDownList("DeclineReasons", ViewBag.DeclineReasons as SelectList, new { @id=item.ProfessorSubmittedRequestFlowId+"Dec" ", @class = "Mychosen"})
</div> and then  (".Mychosen").val()

Comment: Yes,But Then there Will Be Multi DropDowns that wil be selected,Because every record will have dropdown with @class = "Mychosen".,actually Now I Found The Problem,I change var e = document.getElementById("SelectedDeclineReason"); to var e = document.getElementById(SelectedDeclineReason);.

Comment: So you can find by ID wich start widh Dec for example $( "input[Id^='Dec']" ).val()

Comment: No  this way  var e = document.getElementById(SelectedDeclineReason);  For Example ProfessorSubmittedRequestFlowId =09b340e5-e367-4981-9439-4be4f785065b so the id of dropdownlist will be '09b340e5-e367-4981-9439-4be4f785065b+Dec'

Answer (score 0):

I Found The Answer,

```
 var SelectedDeclineReason = ProfessorSubmittedRequestFlowId + "Dec"
  var e = document.getElementById(SelectedDeclineReason);
  var SDeclineReasons = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

I accidentally Use string, I Set Value of SelectedDeclineReason ,and Problem Solved.